# Is it safe to use base64 encoded images for web, Advantages and Disadvantages?

Tags: html, base64, image, frontend

Is it safe to use base64 encoded images for web design, How does it compare in performance? Advantages and Disadvantages?

Comment: A base64 stream is about 33% heavier than a binary one.

Comment: In what context ? Are you speaking of putting the base64 image directly in the page ?

Comment: wondering why would some1 do that.. CDN can help if PERFORMANCE is ur main criteria

Comment: It *might* seem cleaner in some way to have only one html file and no dependency.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A base64 stream is about 33% heavier than a binary one (not taking into account the gzip compression over http that you have in place if you're serious about performances).

If you put the base64 image directly in a page, it won't be cached separately. So it will be heavy for all pages using this image instead of being cachable with URL as key. You may think that it helps keeping the request number low but in fact it's useless in normal cases where users have yet the images in their cache (if you have many images, prefer css sprites to lower the number of requests).

I don't think there is a reason to use a base64 image except for when addressing a specific technical issue, like sending an image in json, or saving only one html file - and then check you really need to use the base64 image.

Comment: its interesting that visual studio web essentials has added this "feature" to convert images to base64 - it just encourages bad practice, your better off serving images from a optimised CDN